# How can I configure karma+istanbul to ignore coffeescript metacode?

Tags: coffeescript, istanbul

I have karma-coverage (istanbul) setup & I love it, but it always fails coverage on this coffeescript line:

```
var bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
```

How can I configure istanbul+karma+coffeescript to skip this line in coverage?

Here is my karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
  'components/**/*.coffee',
  'spec/**/*.coffee'
],

# Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  "karma-coffee-preprocessor",
  "karma-coverage"
],

reporters: ['coverage'],

preprocessors: {
  '**/*.coffee': ['coffee'],
  'components/**/*.coffee': ['coverage']
}
```